# Including DShow.h breaks VCL AnsiString::sprintf() on BDS2006

Tags: c++, c++builder, directshow, ansistring

I finally got some time to upgrade my video capture class.  I wanted to compare **VFW** (what I have used until now) and **DirectShow**. As expected, **DirectShow** is faster, but when I added info texts, suddenly `AnsiString::sprint()` is no longer a member of `AnsiString`.

After some struggle, I found a workaround as `AnsiString::printf()` still works, but I am curious how to fix this. Maybe some define from `dshow.h` and `dstring.h` are conflicting?

I cut down all the unnecessary code to show this problem:

```cpp
//$$---- Form CPP ----
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#include <vcl.h>
#include <dshow.h>
#pragma hdrstop

#include "Unit1.h"
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#pragma package(smart_init)
#pragma resource "*.dfm"
TForm1 *Form1;
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
__fastcall TForm1::TForm1(TComponent* Owner)
    : TForm(Owner)
{
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::Timer1Timer(TObject *Sender)
{
    static int i=0;
    Caption=AnsiString().sprintf("%i",i);               // this does not work
    AnsiString s; s.printf("%i",i); Caption=s;  // this does work
    i++;
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

It is just a simple VCL Form app with a single `TTimer` on it. The `TTimer` is incrementing the counter `i` and outputting it in the Form's `Caption`. The **DirectX** libs are not even linked, just headers included!

The Linker outputs error:

```
[C++ Error] Unit1.cpp(20): E2316 'sprintf_instead_use_StringCbPrintfA_or_StringCchPrintfA' is not a member of 'AnsiString'
```

If I swap the `vcl.h` and dshow.h`includes, the compiler stops in`dstring.h` on this line:

```
AnsiString& __cdecl         sprintf(const char* format, ...); // Returns *this
```

With this error message:

```
[C++ Error] dstring.h(59): E2040 Declaration terminated incorrectly
```

So, there is clearly some conflict (the `AnsiString` keyword is the problem). Putting `dshow.h` into a `namespace` does not help, either.

Does anyone have any clues?

**Q1. How to fix this?**

**Q2. What/where exactly is causing this?**

The only solution that I can think of, and should work (but I want to avoid it if I can), is to create an **OBJ** (or **DLL**) with the **DirectShow** stuff, and then link that into a standard **VCL** project without including `dshow.h` in it, and of course the exports must be without any funny stuff, too.

Comment: try "#undef sprintf" after including dshow.h

Comment: @JeffRSon yes it works make an answer so I can accept it it is odd as VCL is included before DShow ... but it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not with `dshow.h` itself, but is actually with `strsafe.h` instead, which `dshow.h` includes by default.

`strsafe.h` contains the following code <sup>1</sup>:

```
#ifndef STRSAFE_NO_DEPRECATE
// Deprecate all of the unsafe functions to generate compiletime errors. If you do not want
// this then you can #define STRSAFE_NO_DEPRECATE before including this file
#ifdef DEPRECATE_SUPPORTED

...
#pragma deprecated(sprintf)
...

#else // DEPRECATE_SUPPORTED

...
#undef sprintf
#define sprintf     sprintf_instead_use_StringCchPrintfA_or_StringCbPrintfA;
...

#endif  // DEPRECATE_SUPPORTED
#endif  // !STRSAFE_NO_DEPRECATE
```

<sup>1</sup> There are similar `#pragma` and `#define` statements for many other deprecated "unsafe" C functions.

If both `STRSAFE_NO_DEPRECATE` and `DEPRECATE_SUPPORTED` are not defined (which is the case in this situation), the use of `#define sprintf` causes **all subsequent references to *any kind* of `sprintf` symbol** to be seen as `sprintf_instead_use_StringCchPrintfA_or_StringCbPrintfA;` during compiling.

That is why you are getting the compiler error.  When `vcl.h` is included before `strsafe.h`, `dstring.h` gets included first, so the compiler sees the *correct* declaration for the `AnsiString::sprintf()` method, and then `strsafe.h` gets included (presumably by `Unit1.h`) before the compiler sees your `Timer1Timer()` code, so your calls to `AnsiString().sprint("%i",i)` are actually trying to call `AnsiString().sprintf_instead_use_StringCchPrintfA_or_StringCbPrintfA;("%i",i)`, which fail.

When you swap the `vcl.h` and `dshow.h` includes, the `#define sprintf` statement in `strsafe.h` gets processed before `dstring.h` is included, so the compiler sees the following declaration for the `AnsiString::sprintf()` method in `dstring.h` and fails:

```
AnsiString& __cdecl         sprintf_instead_use_StringCchPrintfA_or_StringCbPrintfA;(const char* format, ...); // Returns *this
```

To prevent this behavior, you *could* use an `#undef sprintf` statement after `#include <dshow.h>`, like JeffRSon suggested.  However the **correct** solution is to define `STRSAFE_NO_DEPRECATE` before `#include <strsafe.h>`.  You can do that by either:

1. adding `#define STRSAFE_NO_DEPRECATE` to your code before the `#include <dshow.h>` statement
2. adding `STRSAFE_NO_DEPRECATE` to the Conditionals list in your Project Options.

This solution is described on MSDN:

[About Strsafe.h](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647466.aspx)

> - When you include Strsafe.h in your file, the older functions replaced by the Strsafe.h functions will be deprecated. Attempts to use these older functions will result in a compiler error telling you to use the newer functions. If you want to override this behavior, include the following statement before including Strsafe.h.
>
>   ```
>   #define STRSAFE_NO_DEPRECATE
>   ```
> - To allow only character count functions, include the following statement before including Strsafe.h.
>
>   ```
>   #define STRSAFE_NO_CB_FUNCTIONS
>   ```
> - To allow only byte count functions, include the following statement before including Strsafe.h.
>
>   ```
>   #define STRSAFE_NO_CCH_FUNCTIONS
>   ```

Another supported solution is to define `NO_DSHOW_STRSAFE` before `#include <dshow.h>` so that it will not include `strsafe.h` anymore, thanks to this code in `dshow.h`:

```
#ifndef NO_DSHOW_STRSAFE
#define NO_SHLWAPI_STRFCNS
#include <strsafe.h>  
#endif
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't have this very version of dshow.h and dstring.h, so I cannot check it myself, but from the error messages you cite it seems that somewhere in dshow.h or its dependencies they declare an "sprintf" macro. You may look if you can find it.

In order to prevent that behaviour you need to delete this macro. Use

```
#undef sprintf
```

after the line that includes dshow.h.

Comment: It's sometimes strange how includes from SDK and vcl influence each other. Is this dshow.h from BDS2006? I remember once I had to #undef StrToInt...

Comment: Yes it is from BDS2006 Turbo C++ Explorer. The linked `strmiids.lib` is from DirectX9.2 (BCB version) and works. I am not that familiar with DirectX use just DInput and in the past also DSound but that was a bust as it was unusable due to latency and non working callbacks at that time ...  But have some fun with some MSVC++ style sources under BCB and some includes are mes of defines and include order ...

Comment: Sorry for the un-accept but the other answer is simply better/safer